# How do I add users on workspace through API in Clockify

Tags: clockify

I understand the reason for protecting endpoints with reCapture, but what is the reason to declare a call for adding new users  https://clockify.github.io/clockify_api_docs/#operation--workspaces--workspaceId--users-post if the only response is `{'message': 'reCaptcha was not successfully validated.', 'code': 501}`?

How is it planned in Clockify to add users to a workspace through API?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  Note however that that is the unstable api, and the add user function is not yet in the stable api https://clockify.me/developers-api